# Widget to display Outlook calendar

Tags: calendar, app-widgets, outlook

I am coming to Android from Windows Phone and trying to replicate my old experience, which included showing my next appointment on the home screen. I understand there are things called widgets that can do this. My problem is that every widget I've tried shows my "Google Calendar" (which seems to consist in its entirety of public holidays) rather than the events in my Outlook calendar. I've installed Outlook on the phone and if I click the Calendar icon at the bottom, I see the events. But how do I get those to show up in the widgets?

Comment: I don't think Outlook has a calendar widget per se, and it doesn't integrate with the Android system calendar. There is a Uservoice request which seems relevant: [Sync Calendar with Calendars on Device](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293346-outlook-for-android/suggestions/9159964-sync-calendar-with-calendars-on-device).

Comment: @BenCreasy I added an answer that includes a screenshot showing the Outlook "Agenda" widget

Comment: Cool, I upvoted, but it's still not a full calendar per se.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was never able to make any of the "top" calendar widgets, including those recommended here, show my Outlook calendar. They just showed my empty Gmail calendar or Google calendar or whatever.

**However** I eventually discovered, way down at the bottom of the widgets list, that there was already an Outlook widget installed and waiting for me:

[image: widgets]

Putting the Outlook Agenda on my "desktop" does exactly what I want:

[image: appointments]

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of [calendar widget apps you can download from the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=calendar%20widget&c=apps&hl=en), and a lot of them you can choose which of your personal calendars to display. There are also plenty of apps that just show agenda content- like your next appointment in a nice text widget.

Personally, what I use is [Kustom Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kustom.widget&hl=en), where you can make your own agenda widget.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]